# remove empty array from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
$cal = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => '*',
            1 => 2,
            2 => 3,
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => 6,
            1 => 7,
            2 => 8,
            3 => 9,
            4 => 10,
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => '*',
            1 => '*',
            2 => 15,
            3 => '*',
            4 => 17,
        ) ,
        3 => array(
            0 => 20,
            1 => 21,
            2 => 22,
            3 => 23,
            4 => 24,
        ) ,
        4 => array(
            0 => 27,
            1 => 28,
            2 => 29,
            3 => 30,
            4 => 31,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    1 => array(
        0 => array() ,
        1 => array(
            0 => 3,
            1 => 4,
            2 => 5,
            3 => '*',
            4 => 7,
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => 10,
            1 => 11,
            2 => 12,
            3 => 13,
            4 => 14,
        ) ,
        3 => array(
            0 => 17,
            1 => 18,
            2 => 19,
            3 => 20,
            4 => 21,
        ) ,
        4 => array(
            0 => 24,
            1 => 25,
            2 => 26,
            3 => 27,
            4 => 28,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    2 => array(
        0 => array() ,
        1 => array(
            0 => 3,
            1 => 4,
            2 => 5,
            3 => 6,
            4 => '*',
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => 10,
            1 => 11,
            2 => 12,
            3 => 13,
            4 => 14,
        ) ,
        3 => array(
            0 => 17,
            1 => 18,
            2 => 19,
            3 => 20,
            4 => 21,
        ) ,
        4 => array(
            0 => 24,
            1 => 25,
            2 => 26,
            3 => 27,
            4 => 28,
        ) ,
        5 => array(
            0 => 31,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    3 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 1,
            1 => 2,
            2 => 3,
            3 => 4,
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => 7,
            1 => 8,
            2 => 9,
            3 => 10,
            4 => 11,
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => 14,
            1 => 15,
            2 => 16,
            3 => 17,
            4 => 18,
        ) ,
        3 => array(
            0 => 21,
            1 => 22,
            2 => 23,
            3 => 24,
            4 => 25,
        ) ,
        4 => array(
            0 => 28,
            1 => 29,
            2 => 30,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    4 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 1,
            1 => 2,
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => '*',
            1 => '*',
            2 => '*',
            3 => 8,
            4 => 9,
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => 12,
            1 => 13,
            2 => 14,
            3 => 15,
            4 => 16,
        ) ,
        3 => array(
            0 => 19,
            1 => 20,
            2 => 21,
            3 => 22,
            4 => 23,
        ) ,
        4 => array(
            0 => 26,
            1 => 27,
            2 => 28,
            3 => 29,
            4 => 30,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    5 => array(
        0 => array() ,
        1 => array(
            0 => 3,
            1 => '*',
            2 => 5,
            3 => 6,
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => 9,
            1 => 10,
            2 => 11,
            3 => 12,
            4 => '*',
        ) ,
        3 => array(
            0 => 16,
            1 => 17,
            2 => 18,
            3 => 19,
            4 => 20,
        ) ,
        4 => array(
            0 => 23,
            1 => 24,
            2 => 25,
            3 => 26,
            4 => 27,
        ) ,
        5 => array(
            0 => 30,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    6 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 1,
            1 => 2,
            2 => 3,
            3 => 4,
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => 7,
            1 => 8,
            2 => 9,
            3 => 10,
            4 => 11,
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => 14,
            1 => 15,
            2 => 16,
            3 => 17,
            4 => 18,
        ) ,
        3 => array(
            0 => 21,
            1 => 22,
            2 => 23,
            3 => 24,
            4 => 25,
        ) ,
        4 => array(
            0 => 28,
            1 => 29,
            2 => 30,
            3 => 31,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    7 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 1,
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => 4,
            1 => 5,
            2 => 6,
            3 => 7,
            4 => 8,
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => 11,
            1 => 12,
            2 => 13,
            3 => 14,
            4 => 15,
        ) ,
        3 => array(
            0 => 18,
            1 => 19,
            2 => 20,
            3 => 21,
            4 => 22,
        ) ,
        4 => array(
            0 => 25,
            1 => 26,
            2 => 27,
            3 => 28,
            4 => 29,
        ) ,
        5 => array() ,
    ) ,
    8 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 1,
            1 => 2,
            2 => 3,
            3 => 4,
            4 => 5,
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => 8,
            1 => 9,
            2 => 10,
            3 => 11,
            4 => 12,
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => 15,
            1 => 16,
            2 => 17,
            3 => 18,
            4 => 19,
        ) ,
        3 => array(
            0 => 22,
            1 => 23,
            2 => 24,
            3 => 25,
            4 => 26,
        ) ,
        4 => array(
            0 => 29,
            1 => 30,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    9 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 1,
            1 => 2,
            2 => 3,
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => '*',
            1 => '*',
            2 => '*',
            3 => '*',
            4 => '*',
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => '*',
            1 => '*',
            2 => '*',
            3 => '*',
            4 => '*',
        ) ,
        3 => array(
            0 => 20,
            1 => 21,
            2 => 22,
            3 => 23,
            4 => 24,
        ) ,
        4 => array(
            0 => 27,
            1 => 28,
            2 => 29,
            3 => 30,
            4 => 31,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    10 => array(
        0 => array() ,
        1 => array(
            0 => 3,
            1 => '*',
            2 => 5,
            3 => 6,
            4 => 7,
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => 10,
            1 => 11,
            2 => 12,
            3 => 13,
            4 => 14,
        ) ,
        3 => array(
            0 => 17,
            1 => 18,
            2 => 19,
            3 => 20,
            4 => 21,
        ) ,
        4 => array(
            0 => 24,
            1 => 25,
            2 => 26,
            3 => '*',
            4 => 28,
        ) ,
        5 => array() ,
    ) ,
    11 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => '*',
            1 => 2,
            2 => 3,
            3 => 4,
            4 => '*',
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => 8,
            1 => 9,
            2 => 10,
            3 => 11,
            4 => 12,
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => 15,
            1 => 16,
            2 => 17,
            3 => 18,
            4 => 19,
        ) ,
        3 => array(
            0 => 22,
            1 => 23,
            2 => 24,
            3 => 25,
            4 => 26,
        ) ,
        4 => array(
            0 => 29,
            1 => 30,
            2 => 31,
        ) ,
    ) ,
)
```

I'm trying to remove empty array from its parent using the following code:

```
for($m = 0; $m < count($cal); $m++){
    for($w = 0; $w < count($cal[$m]); $w++){
        if(empty($cal[$m][$w])){
            array_shift($cal[$m]);
        }
    }
}
```

the result is **(please see index 10)**

```
10 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 10,
            1 => 11,
            2 => 12,
            3 => 13,
            4 => 14,
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => 17,
            1 => 18,
            2 => 19,
            3 => 20,
            4 => 21,
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            0 => 24,
            1 => 25,
            2 => 26,
            3 => '*',
            4 => 28,
        ) ,
        3 => array() ,
    ) ,
```

what i expect is remove the first and the last, it is instead remove first and second array and leave the last array still there. any idea?

Comment: `array_shift` removes a element from the beginning of the array

Comment: array_shift removes (and returns) always the first element of the given array. Why don't you use unset instead?

Comment: oh yes i forget about that, instead of using array_shift i should remove the array by its index, am i right?

Comment: `$cal = array_map('array_filter', $cal);` will also do the same job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `array_filter()` instead since `array_shift()` just takes care of the first element:

```
foreach ($cal as &$value) {
    $value = array_filter($value);
}
```

Comment: @DarielPratama just add `$value = array_values($value);` to reset their respective indices

Answer (score 0):

Use unset($cal[$m][$w]) instead of array_shift($cal[$m]).

This will result in

```
10 => array(
    1 => array(
        0 => 3,
        1 => '*',
        2 => 5,
        3 => 6,
        4 => 7,
    ) ,
    2 => array(
        0 => 10,
        1 => 11,
        2 => 12,
        3 => 13,
        4 => 14,
    ) ,
    3 => array(
        0 => 17,
        1 => 18,
        2 => 19,
        3 => 20,
        4 => 21,
    ) ,
    4 => array(
        0 => 24,
        1 => 25,
        2 => 26,
        3 => '*',
        4 => 28,
    ) ,
) ,
```

Notice the key [0] is no longer present

Comment: add the line $cal[$m] = array_values($cal[$m]) after the second for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple recursive function to traverse each like this:

```
<?php

    function removeEmpties(&$array)
    {
        foreach($array as $key=>$val)
        {
            if(count($val)==0)
            {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
            else
            {
                removeEmpties($val);
            }
        }
    }

    $yourArray=array( ... etc );
    removeEmpties($yourArray);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
foreach ($cal as &$arr)
{
  $arr = array_filter($arr); 
}

$cal = array_filter($cal);
```